# What does it mean for a vector space to be self-dual?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

The Euclidean space is sometimes said to be "self-dual". I was wondering what this term actually means, because I couldn't find definitions of it when this "self-duality" is mentioned.

I find it a bit confusing because the elements of the dual vector space are supposed to be linear functionals, so I don't quite see how a vector space can be "the same" as its dual. For example, in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the inner product $\langle x, y \rangle = x^T y$, does it make sense to refer to $x^T$ as an element of the dual space? In what way is the Euclidean space "self-dual"? Is every inner product space self-dual in this way?

I'd appreciate any elaboration on these ideas!

Comment: Well, every complete inner product space is self-dual in this way.  Infinite dimensional vector spaces are weird.

Comment: Instead of saying "self-dual", some would say "canonically isomorphic to its dual".

Comment: Means, *isomorphic to its dual*.  It is the case with all finite-dimensional vector spaces, but is generally falls for the infinite-dimensional normed ones (e.g., false for the $L^{p}$-spaces).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom +1 for mentioning the weirdness of those beasts.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, if you say "canonically isomorphic", this requires clarifying what isomorphisms would count as "canonical".

Comment: @avs sure.  In this case, the map $x \mapsto \langle x, \cdot \rangle$ (i.e. $x \mapsto x^T$) is the canonical isomorphism.  This map is "canonical" in that it can be applied to any inner product space in terms of structures universally applicable to inner product spaces without further specification, (for example, specifying a basis).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It seems that your definition of self-duality is different from the one given by avs, as you require the isomorphism to be "canonical". Is there no single agreed-upon notion of self-duality?

Comment: @Tray, for finite-dimensional spaces, one can define "canonical" as follows: take a basis in the original vector space, and then construct its *dual basis* in the dual space (essentially what Omnomnomnom did).  The two bases have the same number of vectors, hence the isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Self-dual" is not commonly used as a term with a precise definition in this context.  When someone says that a vector space $V$ is self-dual, that normally means (at a minimum) that there exists an isomorphism $V\to V^*$ from $V$ to its dual space.  Depending on context, it may also mean that a *specific* such isomorphism has been chosen, or that there is a specific canonical such isomorphism which can be defined in terms of some extra structure that $V$ has.

So in the first, weakest sense, where you just say there exists an isomorphism, every finite-dimensional vector space is self-dual.  Given a vector space $V$ with a bilinear form $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$, there is a canonical map $f:V\to V^*$ which takes $v\in V$ to the functional $w\mapsto\langle v,w\rangle$.  If the bilinear form is nondegenerate, then $f$ is injective.  If $V$ is additionally finite-dimensional, then $f$ is automatically surjective as well.  So any finite-dimensional vector space with a nondegenerate bilinear form (e.g., an inner product) is self-dual in the stronger sense of having a canonical isomorphism to its dual determined by its extra structure.

(In fact, conversely, an isomorphism $V\to V^*$ determines a nondegenerate bilinear form by reversing the construction above, so fixing such an isomorphism on a finite-dimensional vector space is equivalent to choosing a nondegenerate bilinear form.)